# Postman Monitoring request error "Error: NETERR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost"

Tags: postman, monitoring, rest

I am trying to figure out how to get monitoring to work in Postman.

I have written tests on the desktop client for get/create/put and everything works fine. I'm using a localhost address and port 5004 which is the port for the API.

http://127.0.0.1:5004/bookings

I have tried to change the proxy in setting to localhost and port 5004, I have tried to change it to 127.0.0.1:5004, I have tried to disable SSL on the desktop client.  I am running the monitoring on using the desktop client from the browser, that doesn't work either.

[image: The error log:]

[image: I've tried it with https and without]

I have also checked if my etc/host file contains 127.0.0.1  localhost and it does.

Not sure what else I can try, I would appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Accessible APIs:
>
> Monitors require all URLs to be publicly available on the internet as
> they run in the Postman cloud. A monitor cannot directly access your
> localhost or run requests behind a firewall. However, to overcome this
> issue, static IPs are available on Postman Business and Enterprise
> plans.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/monitoring-your-api/intro-monitors/

you cannot use the monitor for inhouse and localhost websites, You could upgrade to enterprise or business plans and see if that helps

Answer (score 8):

The issue is maybe you configured the environment variable and passed the correct value in the URL also

But while running the collection test class
**didn't select the correct environment**

Select the environment configured to run that collection, shown in attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and the issue was my DNS address. After changing the DNS server it was solved.

Comment: OP is using localhost. DNS is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had space between ip and :port =>0.0.0.0b:1111 in my env. I deleted the space and I can connect. => 0.0.0.0:1111.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it got solved by removing the env variable

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not the env variables that caused this error but the server being unavailable/down due to server team work on it.

Answer (score -2):

what you should try is sign out, sign in again. make sure the environment variables are not empty.
also, try using the feature console.log(get environment variable name) it would be helpful.
make sure to click on persist all in the environment variable.
The key for me was to click on "persist all" in the environment variable

[read the github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6001#issuecomment-1155377029)

[some comments which helped me resolve the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyhPe.png)